# Single-page.php template file name not shown

Tags: templates, page-template, template-hierarchy

I am developing a theme and I noticed that

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);
```

returns 'static-page.php' (as expected) when queried on static pages but returns nothing (expected 'single-post.php') when queried on a single blog post pages.

I have single-post.php file set up and working, content displayed, etc. But I can't get template file name for some reason on this page. It works just fine on static pages. Any ideas why?

Comment: `_wp_page_template` is the meta value that's stored when a post or page is using a custom template. It's not used if it's using the default template. Is there a particular reason you need to know the name? If it's just for debugging, then the Query Monitor plugin can tell you which templates are in use.

Comment: I am using the template file name in the html <head> section to load corresponding css files. For static-page.php I am loading static-page.css, similarly for single-post.php I would like to load single-post.css. As said, it is working fine on my static pages, but returns zero on single blog post page.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using the template file name in the  section to load
>   corresponding css files. For static-page.php I am loading
>   static-page.css, similarly for single-post.php I would like to load
>   single-post.css. As said, it is working fine on my static pages, but
>   returns zero on single blog post page.

This isn't really the correct way to do this. For starters you shouldn't be placing anything in `<head>` directly. Instead you should be 'enqueueing' the styles from your functions file, [as outlined in the Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/).

When you do it this way you can use the [Conditional Tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) to determine what is currently being viewed, and enqueue the appropriate styles.

For example, if you want to load styles for single posts only, you'd use `is_singular( 'post' )`., while for custom page templates you'd use `is_page_template( 'static-page.php' );`.

Comment: Thank you Jacob for explanation and references. This method of using is_single () works just fine. I am aware of WP recommendations and will definitely move to WP suggested method at a later stage. I haven't learned that yet, and I need to get quick result at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I am working today to upgrade my theme as per Jacob's earlier suggestion. I removed all the stylesheet links from header.php and put them into functions.php.

The non-conditional stylesheets and those stylesheets which are connected using is_page_template() work without any issue.

However, the stylesheets which are connected using is_category, is_tag, etc. do not work.

Here's the code:

```
function add_styles () {

    // Styles for all pages - work just fine

        wp_enqueue_style( 'normalize', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/normalize.css', false, '1', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/main.css', false, '1', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'header', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/header.css', false, '1', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'index', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/index.css', false, '1', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'functions', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/functions.css', false, '1', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'footer', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/footer.css', false, '1', 'all' );

    // Styles for custom template pages - DO NOT work

        if ( is_category() ) { wp_enqueue_style( 'category', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/category.css', false, '1', 'all' ); };
        if ( is_tag() ) { wp_enqueue_style( 'tag', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/tag.css', false, '1', 'all' ); };
        if ( is_single() ) { wp_enqueue_style( 'single', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/single-post.css', false, '1', 'all' ); };
        if ( is_date() ) { wp_enqueue_style( 'date', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/date.css', false, '1', 'all' ); };

    // Styles for static page templates - DO work

        if ( is_page_template('front-page.php') ) { wp_enqueue_style( 'front-page', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/front-page.css', false, '1', 'all' ); };
        if ( is_page_template('static-page.php') ) { wp_enqueue_style( 'static-page', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/static-page.css', false, '1', 'all' ); };
        if ( is_page_template('landing-page.php') ) { wp_enqueue_style( 'landing-page', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/landing-page.css', false, '1', 'all' ); };
        if ( is_page_template('404.php') ) { wp_enqueue_style( '404', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/404.css', false, '1', 'all' ); };

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_styles' );
```

It is clear that is_category, is_tag, etc. do not work. From reading CODEX and the internet I figured out that they are called from functions.php too early. However, I can't understand how to hook them properly so that they work.

What would be the right way to do this?